# Parse standardised HTML in iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, html-parsing

I am working on an iOS application that pulls in content as html. It's not ideal, but is all that I have to work with at the moment. Anyway, the html is in the following standard format:

```
....Any old html up to this point...
<div class="content odd"> Lorem ipsum... </div>
<div class="content even"> Lorem ipsum... </div>
<div class="content odd"> Lorem ipsum... </div>
<div class="content even"> Lorem ipsum... </div>
....Any old html after this point...
```

What would be the best way for me to parse this?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/topfunky/hpple.  It seems to handle the mess that is html pretty well.