# how parse HTML in Objective C

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, parsing

Any body could help me please!
I want to parse some HTML code from web for Objective C, the HTML codes are like bellow:

```
<div class="linkSummary">
<a href="video_page.php?id=2309"><img class="video_thumbnail" width="120" height="90" src="video_thumbnails/vthumb_2309.jpg"></a>


<div class="video_title"><a href="video_page.php?id=2309">المپیک لندن؛ اهداء مدال کشتی فرنگی ۵۵ کیلوگرم </a></div>
<div class="video_league"><a href="videos.php?cupID=23">المپیک لندن</a></div>
<div class="video_date">&#1777;&#1781; &#1605;&#1585;&#1583;&#1575;&#1583; &#1777;&#1779;&#1785;&#1777; (<span dir="ltr">5 August 2012</span>)</div>
<div class="send_details">
    <span class="icon_holder"><img width="22" height="25" class="rollover v1" src="image_slices/icon_ball_off.jpg" hover="image_slices/icon_ball_on.jpg" vid="1" otid="4" oid="2309"><img width="22" height="25" class="rollover v2" src="image_slices/icon_yellow_off.jpg" hover="image_slices/icon_yellow_on.jpg" vid="2" otid="4" oid="2309"><img width="22" height="25" class="rollover v3" src="image_slices/icon_red_off.jpg" hover="image_slices/icon_red_on.jpg" vid="3" otid="4" oid="2309"></span>&#1578;&#1575; &#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1606; &#1777;&#1780; &#1606;&#1592;&#1585; &#1583;&#1585; &#1605;&#1608;&#1585;&#1583; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1608;&#1740;&#1583;&#1740;&#1608; &#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1607; &#1588;&#1583;&#1607; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;. | <a href="video_page.php?id=2309">&#1606;&#1592;&#1585; &#1588;&#1605;&#1575; &#1670;&#1740;&#1607;&#1567;</a>
</div>

</div>
```

I want parser to parse video_title and the image that associated to that title, and put these into a table. Anybody could show me some sample code to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674342/parse-standardised-html-in-ios-application

Comment: A quick search for "parse html objective-c" shows dozens of relevant questions.

Comment: @Tim *possible* duplicate, yes. But the accepted answer on that question is *waaaaaay* too complicated.  A simple `NSXMLParser` will suffice.

Comment: Should I exchange HTML to XML? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may find that [ElementParser](https://github.com/Objective3/ElementParser) works for you. It provides some very useful methods for getting data out of an HTML document using CSS selectors, similar to jQuery. The documentation is a little light, but [an intro to using it is available](http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/).